# Procedure entry point not found when using SDL2 and SDL2_image

Tags: c++, linker, sdl, program-entry-point, sdl-image

I get an entry point not found error when trying to use `SDL2 2.26.5 x64` in conjuction with `SDL2_image 2.6.3 x64`, and calling IMG_Init(). include paths, linker stuff all set up like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

so everything is set up correctly afaik.
The full error states:

[image]

What i find weird about this error is that the function SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat is a thing in the SDL2 library. Why is it trying to access this function in the SDL2_image library? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: There's a section in the answer dealing specifically with this error.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I am using a template and there was a very sneaky folder with another older sdl2 dll, thanks.